# Catch RowEdited event in DataGrid WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, datagrid

How to catch event when DataGrid's row was edited and get all values from it?

If I use RowEditEnding event, I can't get new values...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See the discussion [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/d9afc793-ec66-428f-a087-bccbbcffda73), and this solution:

```
private void OnRowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
    if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit) {
        ListCollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid.ItemsSource) as ListCollectionView;
        if (view.IsAddingNew || view.IsEditingItem) {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new DispatcherOperationCallback(param => 
            { 
                // This callback will be called after the CollectionView
                // has pushed the changes back to the DataGrid.ItemSource.

                // Write code here to save the data to the database.
                return null; 
            }), DispatcherPriority.Background, new object[] { null });
        }
    }
}
```